# How to print compacted points in pure C, so they can be seen as a single mathematical figure (line, square, rectangle, etc.)?

Tags: c, terminal, console, printf

In the following code I'm printing 10 points in a straight line. How can I make these points be compacted so that someone can see all of them as an almost continuous line without, using any graphical library?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%c", '.');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by compacted? Do you want something like `---------`?

Comment: That's not the way periods work. In a console, you're working with a specific font. That font defines that a point looks the way it does, you can't overlap characters in a console.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: @PiRocks no, I want something like __________

Comment: @ThomasJager, what a pity for me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm afraid I can't!

Comment: Do you all mean if I want to create figures over the console using points, I'll have to use figures with all points visible as points? How do libraries like `graphics.h` reached this goal?

Comment: @MoisésFerreira they put the sceen in a special graphic mode.

Comment: @Jabberwocky can you help me to put the screen in a special graphic mode as well?

Comment: @MoisésFerreira this question is far too broad. What is your platform?

Comment: I'm using a Mac OS terminal. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't know if Mac OS terminal supports Unicode line drawing characters, but if it does you could use those.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close because an adequate answer to this question would require a specific console and font, which is not given.

Answer (score 1):

```
          ,
         _o_
    ._ ,'   `o'
----(_)      :       ^aNT
    '  `.   .o
         ~o~  `
          '
```

A "picture" is worth a thousand words.

Comment: How do  libraries like `graphics.h` reached the goal I want?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make these points be compacted so that someone can see all of them as an almost continuous line without, using any graphical library?

You can´t do that by using points. You need to print f.e. subsequent `_` characters to print a line, f.e.:

```
printf("_______________");
```

If you want to use vertical lines, use the `|` character in subsequent calls to printf:

```
printf("|\n");
printf("|\n");
printf("|\n");
printf("|\n");
```

or just

```
printf("|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n");
```

One example:

`````
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
   printf("___________________________\n");
   printf("|    ````        ````     |\n");
   printf("|      X         X        |\n");
   printf("|           O             |\n");
   printf("|                         |\n");
   printf("|   |________________|    |\n");
   printf("|         |____|          |\n");
   printf("|_________________________|\n");
}
`````

Output:

`````
___________________________       
|    ````       ````      |              
|      X         X        |            
|           O             |      
|                         |                               
|   |________________|    |           
|         |____|          |  
|_________________________|
`````

It is not the most beautiful look but that should achieve what you want as far as I understood your question. You don´t need special libraries to accomplish simple graphical illustrations in the console.

> How to print compacted points in pure C, so they can be seen as a single mathematical figure (line, square, rectangle, etc.)?

A console is not meant to output shapes and figures like that. Maybe there are some terminals with special fonts, but it is hard if not impossible to achieve.

Comment: How could you print a diagonal line (for a rectangle) or a circule using this approach?

Comment: A raw and nasty diagonal line with f.e. the \ or / character. A circle seems impossible. Note, that a console windows is not meant for output such graphics.

Comment: I can print everything on the console with points, even  circles. I just wanted  a better way to present it in a more compact way.

Comment: @MoisésFerreira I´m meant impossible to write in such "compact" way that the specific points would blur into each other and the result would be an circle without any gap between points.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!